# How to find out who is still sending TLS 1.0 mails to Salesforce

Tags: email, tls

We are getting mails from Salesforce (the company) warning that incoming or outgoing mails to/from Salesforce (the system) are still using TLS 1.0. The warning is not more explicit, it says incoming or outgoing. Support for TLS 1.0 will be stopped at March 6, one month from now.

So we checked outgoing (that is easy) and incoming (a bit more difficult) mails, using test messages. Both are using TLS 1.2, I have the logging and mail headers to prove it.

I cannot find a report that tells us which mail clients still send TLS 1.0 mails. We would like to know, of course. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You checked if your customers are still using TLS 1.0? You may have a customer that you either send email to or receive email from that is using TLS 1.0

Comment: @Sean We have a lot of customers. Asking them to find out which TLS version they are using would be too difficult for 98% of them. And we don't want to bother all of them, while maybe only one of them may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Apex email services, you can update your `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler` class(es) to extract the `X-SFDC-TLS-VERSION` header from the `Messaging.InboundEmail` and log it somewhere, e.g.

```
global class EmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
   global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
      Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
      for (Messaging.InboundEmail.Header h : email.headers) {
         if (h.name == 'X-SFDC-TLS-VERSION' && h.value == 'TLSv1') {
            result.message += 'Upgrade your MTA, dude.\n';
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

[swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) is a useful tool for testing:

```
swaks -t inbound@xxxxx-xx.cs40.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com -f me@example.com --tls --tls-protocol tlsv1
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed we have several email handlers that we made ourselves. But there is also the standard Salesforce feature, with the very long email address, that users can use to forward mails to Salesforce (for association with Accounts, Contacts, Opp's). I don't know how I can check those mails.